# Jquery Progress Bar ui-progress-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

Im getting an error and I cant figure out how to fix it. This code is for a progress bar .

> TypeError: $(...).animateProgress is not a function Line 55

Im not sure whether or not to remove `.fn`  on line 6 but I tried that and nothing happend.

```
 (function( $ ){
// Simple wrapper around jQuery animate to simplify animating progress from your app
// Inputs: Progress as a percent, Callback
// TODO: Add options and jQuery UI support.

$.fn.animateProgress = function(progress, callback) {    
return this.each(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: progress+'%'
  }, {
    duration: 2000, 

    // swing or linear
    easing: 'swing',

    // this gets called every step of the animation, and updates the label
    step: function( progress ){
      var labelEl = $('.ui-label', this),
          valueEl = $('.value', labelEl);

      if (Math.ceil(progress) < 20 && $('.ui-label', this).is(":visible")) {
        labelEl.hide();
      }else{
        if (labelEl.is(":hidden")) {
          labelEl.fadeIn();
        };
      }

      if (Math.ceil(progress) == 100) {
        labelEl.text('Done');
        setTimeout(function() {
          labelEl.fadeOut();
        }, 1000);
      }else{
        valueEl.text(Math.ceil(progress) + '%');
      }
    },
    complete: function(scope, i, elem) {
      if (callback) {
        callback.call(this, i, elem );
      };
    }
  });
  });
};
 })( jQuery );

$(function() {
// Hide the label at start
$('#progress_bar_itm .ui-progress .ui-label').hide();
// Set initial value
$('#progress_bar_itm .ui-progress').css('width', '7%');

// Simulate some progress
$('#progress_bar_itm .ui-progress').animateProgress(43, function() {
$(this).animateProgress(79, function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#progress_bar_itm .ui-progress').animateProgress(100, function() {
      $('#main_content').slideDown();
      $('#fork_me').fadeIn();
      });
    }, 100);
  });
});

});
```

Comment: Your `jQuery` and `$` are the same thing ?

Comment: ? Sorry I dont userstand which bit are you refering to this part })( jQuery );

Comment: Yes. You registered a function inside the closure on the `$` object, which was in fact `jQuery`. Then you tried to access the function outside the closure but it seems that it isn't registered at all.